# finding regression to second order poynomial python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a piece of code below and want to find the regression to the line (how good the data points match this line). I want my fit to be second order polynomial. How can i do this? and is there a method which takes errors into consideration.

```
plt.errorbar(x,y,fmt='*')
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
xxx=np.linspace(0.65,2,10)
ppp = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(xxx,ppp(xxx))
```

Comment: Have you looked at scipy? I think scipy.stats.linregress is what you are looking for.

Comment: this is just linear not second order polynommials

Comment: Can you be more specific please. `regression to the line` is unclear. Do you want to interpolate, do a least squares fit, something else? Also from your comment I assume you want to do it in higher dimensions? You don't mention that in your post...

Comment: yeah sorry, in the code the fits of the data is a second oder polynomial

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation on [numpy.polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html), it can also return residuals, which are the errors you are looking for. Look at the `Returns` section. And you can set the polynomial degree that you want with the parameter `deg`.